# How to get Raven DB index name from clr type

Tags: c#, ravendb

Is there a way I can get index name from corresponding class in c#? For example: I have class named `Users_ByEmail` and I know that Raven created index named `Users/ByEmail` for me, but I want to get it from Raven methods.

I need something like this:

```
public class Users_ByEmail : AbstractIndexCreationTask<User>
....

string indexName = documentStore.GetIndexName(typeof(Users_ByEmail));
```

Is Raven client has any method doing that exposed? This would be useful, because I don't want use strings when calling `UpdateByIndex` method from DataBaseCommands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name by creating an instance of the class and using the `IndexName` property.

```
string indexName = new Users_ByEmail().IndexName;
```

I agree it would be nice if the API had some overloads that didn't rely on string.  Something like the following would be nice:

```
documentStore.DatabaasCommands.UpdateByIndex<Users_ByEmail>(...)
```

If you have a lot of these calls in your code, you could consider writing an extension method that would give you that.

Comment: Yep. That will do. Thanks!